# How to redirect index.php to another page via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect any request coming on `www.url.com` to `www.url.com/error/error` except only `www.url.com/payment/payment`.

I mean `www.url.com/payment/payment` request only should work.

How it is possible?

```
# .htaccess #

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I have used redirect 404 but while I am access www.url.com/payment/payment this is also redirect to 404

Comment: show your htaccess content.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the below line into your htaccess,

`RewriteRule ^payment/payment payment/payment`

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch directive :

```
RedirectMatch ^/((?!payment/payment/?).+)$ /error/error
```

Comment: @Yogesh I have updated the Redirect pattern. I think it was due to the traling slash in the uri. I added a question mark to make the slash optional. Hope this solves the issue.